# Why does the following code work on online ide(gcc 7.2.0) but gives error on ubuntu?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc

When I run the following code on ubuntu(gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4)):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<list>
using namespace std;
int main(){
vector <int> v;
v.push_back(1);
v.push_back(2);
v.push_back(3);
v.push_back(4);
v.push_back(5);
list<int> temp;
for(auto i:v){
    cout<<i<<" ";
    temp.push_back(i);
}
for(auto i:temp){
    cout<<i<<" ";
}
}
```

I get the following errors:

```
try.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
try.cpp:13:10: error: ‘i’ does not name a type
 for(auto i:v){
          ^
try.cpp:17:1: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘for’
 for(auto i:temp){
 ^
try.cpp:17:1: error: expected primary-expression before ‘for’
try.cpp:17:1: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘for’
try.cpp:17:1: error: expected primary-expression before ‘for’
try.cpp:17:1: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘for’
try.cpp:17:10: error: ‘i’ does not name a type
 for(auto i:temp){
          ^
try.cpp:20:1: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token
 }
 ^
try.cpp:20:1: error: expected primary-expression before ‘}’ token
try.cpp:20:1: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token
try.cpp:20:1: error: expected primary-expression before ‘}’ token
try.cpp:20:1: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘}’ token
try.cpp:20:1: error: expected primary-expression before ‘}’ token
```

But when I run the code on online ide I works  fine.
**What is the problem with the code?**

The link for code on online ide:[No errors](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lUr1XAu9dTTyPoOM)

Comment: How are you compiling on Ubuntu?

Comment: @MichaelAlbers   `g++ -o try try.cpp`

Comment: You don't say what version of gcc you're using on Ubuntu (`gcc --version`), but I'll bet it's old enough that it doesn't support C++ 11 features by default.  Try using the `-std=gnu++11` option.

Comment: @MichaelBurr `gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.`

Comment: @MichaelBurr can I upgrade it?

Comment: gcc 5.4 definitely supports C++11 but not by default - did you try using the option explicitly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code uses some of the C++11 features such as [range based loops](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) and [auto specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) but you don't compile for the C++11 standard. You need to enable the C++11 support by including the `-std=c++11` flag when compiling:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -o try try.cpp
```

The online compiler has this enabled by using the `-std=gnu++1z` flag.